# win32 api c++ :How can i color only some text in color?

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

i have edit text control with text that im loading to it , 
i want some of the text to be in color x and some in color y , how can it be done?
also can i make clickble link inside of the edittext?

```
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOG 0, 0, 369, 318
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Win32 demo"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{

    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2, 8, 1, 353, 86, NOT WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in a standard edit control. You need a rich edit control for that. Based on your previous question I do wonder if what you really need is a hyperlink which you can do with the SysLink control.

Comment: well there is string long one that has some links , its be great if it can be clickable

Comment: SysLink may be your guy in that case. Requires XP and comctl v6 but that should be fine.